# Disable lsp-mode symbol highlighting?

Tags: highlighting, lsp-mode

When using lsp server, symbol highlighting obscures the highlighting done by region selection.  I can toggle this behavior per-buffer with `lsp-toggle-symbol-highlight`, but cannot permanently disable it for all buffers.  Is there a workaround to fix the current lack of a configuration setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the `lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting` option:

```el
(setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil)
```

or via [Easy Customization Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html):

```el
M-x customize-variable <RET> lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting <RET>
```

> Highlight references of the symbol at point.